Making linear to logistic regression with sigmoid function - why is a transformation of predicted y needed?
I noticed that one can run a linear regression for binary outcomes and get the same predictions as from a logistic regression after using a sigmoid function. That is what I awaited. But the surprising part for me is that I needed to transform the predicted values in advance. Here is what I did:

Run a logistic regression for y ~ x, where y is binary and x a continuous random variable.
Made predictions of logits (y_logit) over the range of x with the model I received in step 1.
Applied inverse logit to transform the y_logit values from step 2 to probabilities (y_prob): y_prob <- 1 / (1 + exp(-y_logit)).

Afterwards I started with the OLS:

Run a OLS linear regression for y ~ x.
Made predictions of y over the range of x with the model coefficients I received in step 4: y_pred <- b0 + b1* x.
Run an OLS where I regressed the predicted logits y_logit from step 2 on the predicted y (y_pred) from step 5: y_logit ~ y_pred. This was a perfect linear fit.
Transformed predicted y_pred values from step 5 with the coefficients from model of step 6: y_transformed <- b0' + b1'*y_pred.
Applied a sigmoid function on y_transformed from step 7: y_prob_lm <- 1/ (1 + e^(-y_transformed)).
Compared whether probabilities y_prob from step 3 received by logistic regression are same as the y_prob_lm probabilities recieved by OLS from step 8: Yes, they are the same. y_prob = y_prob_lm.

I thought I could jump from step 5 to step 8, i.e. I thought I could apply the sigmoid function directly on the predicted y values of the OLS (y_pred). But I had to transform them in advance (steps 6 and 7). Why do we need to transform predicted y values before applying the sigmoid function when predicting probabilities with OLS?

Whole story with R. Before getting to steps 1 to 9 we need to generate data:
library(magrittr)
# Generate data
# Make it reproducible
set.seed(1)
# Number of observations.
n <- 100000
# Random x variable.
x <- rnorm(n, 50, 10)
# Coefficients.
b0 <- log(.001)
b_x <- log(1.2)
b_noise <- log(.9)
# Formula.
z <- b0 + b_x* x + b_noise* rnorm(n, 0, 1)
# y.
y <- {1/ (1 + exp(-z))} %>%
  rbinom(n= n, size= 1, prob= .) %>%
  as.logical()

# Make it a dataframe.
df <- data.frame(x, y, y_num= as.numeric(y) - 1) 

Here are the steps 1 to 3 with the logistic regression:
# Fit model (STEP 1).
mod_log <- glm(formula= y ~ x, family= binomial(link="logit"), data= df)

# What values to predict for.
df_pred <- data.frame(x= seq(0, max(x), .1))

# Predict.
# logit predictions (STEP 2)
df_pred$log_logit <- predict(mod_log, newdata= df_pred)
# Apply inverse logit to transform to probabilities (STEP 3)
df_pred$log_prob <- 1 / (1 + exp(-df_pred$log_logit))

plot(df_pred$x, df_pred$log_prob)
# This results in a plausible looking plot.

Steps 4 to 9:
# Run linear model (STEP 4)
mod_lm <- lm(formula= y_num ~ x, data= df)
# Predict y with linear model fit (STEP 5)
df_pred$lm_y <- coef(mod_lm)[1] + coef(mod_lm)[2] *df_pred$x
# Transform y.
df_pred$lm_y_transformed <- data.frame(lm_y= df_pred$lm_y, log_logit=  df_pred$log_logit) %>%
  lm(log_logit ~ lm_y, .) %>% # (STEP 6)
  coef() %>%
  {.[1] + .[2] *df_pred$lm_y} # (STEP 7)
# Apply sigmoid function on y (STEP 8)
df_pred$lm_prob <- 1/(1 + exp(-df_pred$lm_y_transformed))
# Test whether the probabilities are the same (STEP 9).
all.equal(df_pred$log_prob, df_pred$lm_prob)
# TRUE!


Spending time doing ad hoc approaches when logistic regression works just fine is a bit hard to understand.  More importantly, your approach breaks down when an estimated probability is 0 or 1 and you attempt to compute its logit for later steps, as you’ll get infinities.

"when logistic regression works just fine" Yes, I can simply use glm() in R. But this question is not about doing but understanding. It's not "How?" but "Why?"

You’ll need to take logits of 0s or 1s with your algorithm, I think.  Overall guidance: pick a statistical model that respects the nature of the dependent variable.

I understand that this is not how one analysis binary outcomes and that one would rather use glm as in step 1. But this is not the question. The question is why the transformation is needed. I wonder how both methods are connected and maybe an answer to this question can give me some deeper insight
